# Can you run Singular Value Decomposition or PCA on a dataset with lots of Null Values

Tags: null, cluster-analysis, normalization, pca, svd

I have a dataset that has 300 variables, with over 300K observations.  There are some columns that have lots of null values (up to 90% for some variables).  I want to eventually run a clustering algorithm on the dataset, but I need to reduce the number of dimensions first.  I plan to use SVD or PCA.  Will the null values inhibit me from getting proper results when running SVD or PCA?  Is so, any suggestions on what I should do?  Omit or impute the data?

Also, the range of the variables vary significantly.  Should I normalize the data by transforming the values into standard deviations from the mean for the column?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

PCA is O(n*d^3). Given that d is just 300 and n is just 300k, you shouldn't have any issues. Have you actually tried it?